# Dual Monitors on Cinnamon 2.4.8 - cursor gets stuck on bottom and top right of left screen

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, cinnamon, multi-monitor

Running Mint 17.1 with Cinammon 2.4.8 and I have two 2560 * 1440 monitors, both placed in the display settings as next to each other, not mirrored.

The mouse cursor moves as normal between the two monitors, except for about 16 pixels from the top and the bottom of the right hand side of the left monitor. Then the cursor just won't move any further right until I move it more than 16 pixels away from the top or bottom of the screen.

This is about the height of a panel or title bar, so my first thought was to close all applications and try it with an empty desktop. Still happens. Same with moving the taskbar panel from the bottom.

I also tried swapping the displays around but it still happens. Even setting the displays offset so that for example, the cursor coming from halfway down the left screen goes to the top of the right screen or vice versa has no effect; the cursor still gets stuck at the top and bottom 16 pixels of the left screen.

Output of `xdpyinfo`:

```
name of display:    :0
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    11501000
X.Org version: 1.15.1
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes
motion buffer size:  256
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32
image byte order:    LSBFirst
number of supported pixmap formats:    7
supported pixmap formats:
    depth 1, bits_per_pixel 1, scanline_pad 32
    depth 4, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 8, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 15, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 16, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 24, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
    depth 32, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
keycode range:    minimum 8, maximum 255
focus:  window 0x3804196, revert to Parent
number of extensions:    29
    BIG-REQUESTS
    Composite
    DAMAGE
    DOUBLE-BUFFER
    DPMS
    DRI2
    DRI3
    GLX
    Generic Event Extension
    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    MIT-SHM
    Present
    RANDR
    RECORD
    RENDER
    SECURITY
    SGI-GLX
    SHAPE
    SYNC
    X-Resource
    XC-MISC
    XFIXES
    XFree86-DGA
    XFree86-VidModeExtension
    XINERAMA
    XInputExtension
    XKEYBOARD
    XTEST
    XVideo
default screen number:    0
number of screens:    1

screen #0:
  dimensions:    5120x1440 pixels (1355x381 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
  root window id:    0x9f
  depth of root window:    24 planes
  number of colormaps:    minimum 1, maximum 1
  default colormap:    0x22
  default number of colormap cells:    256
  preallocated pixels:    black 0, white 16777215
  options:    backing-store WHEN MAPPED, save-unders NO
  largest cursor:    64x64
  current input event mask:    0xfac033
    KeyPressMask             KeyReleaseMask           EnterWindowMask          
    LeaveWindowMask          KeymapStateMask          ExposureMask             
    StructureNotifyMask      SubstructureNotifyMask   SubstructureRedirectMask 
    FocusChangeMask          PropertyChangeMask       ColormapChangeMask       
  number of visuals:    20
  default visual id:  0x20
  visual:
    visual id:    0x20
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x21
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x8d
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x8e
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x8f
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x90
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x91
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x92
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x93
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x94
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x95
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x96
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x97
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x98
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x99
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x9a
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x9b
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x9c
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x9d
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x60
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    32 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
```

Comment: "Hot corners" feature or screen edge snaps? Sounds like the *slip* used for those features.

Comment: Yes, try changing the hot corners settings.

Comment: Just checked that, all of the options on Hot corners are disabled.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of old, but there is an option in the Cinnamon panel settings to **"Allow the pointer to pass through the edges of the panels"**.  This is disabled by default.  This may be your issue.

[image: panel settings]

It's been a while since I've run 17.1, and my screenshot is from 18.3, but I'm pretty sure the option is still there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the screens have different resolution, specifically the left one is taller and extends both higher and lower than the one on the right.`xdpyinfo` can verify or disprove this.

Comment: They are definitely the same resolution - both 2560 * 1440. The display settings show both screens as this resolution. `xpdyinfo` is saying I have one screen however, with a resolution of 5120 * 1440.